# How to re-render a SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, persistence

I have a homepage which goes to other views without NavigationLinks, but rather with isActive states and pop to root dismissals, as this way, I was told, our app uses less memory as it is cyclic in nature. because of this, the view is never navigated to again, it is always there, and as a result @State vars are never re-evaluated. For example, in our homepage, I have this:

```swift
@State var showSwingAgainSheet = appDelegate.swing?.isRecorded ?? false
```

Which refers to a Core Data variable, and is used later to display a sheet:

```swift
.modifier(SaveOrDeleteRecordingSheetView(isPresented: $showSwingAgainSheet))
```

When the Core Data variable is set to true, the sheet does not pop up unless I force close the app

I have considered using @Environment, @ObservableObject, but could not figure it out. What would be the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Where is core data object? Would you show more code?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance [this](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/) could help?  Changing the .id() modifier reloads the view, causing the @State variables to revert to their default state.  Since the default state is a ternary operator, it might reevaluate it when the view is reloaded.